# How to use sbt-native-packager plug-in v1.9.2 and fix "not found" error?

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to use the latest version of **sbt-native-packager** (v1.9.2) in a Play Framework project:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/tree/v1.9.2

Hence, I have added *this* to the `project/plugins.sbt` file:

```
// SBT Native Packager
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.9.2")
```

However, I'm getting this error now:

```
[info] Resolving com.github.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.9.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.github.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.9.2
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.9.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.9.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.github.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.9.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/sbt/sbt-native-packager_2.10_0.13/1.9.2/sbt-native-packager-1.9.2.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.9.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.9.2 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.github.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.9.2 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/user/Desktop/ra-server/project/plugins.sbt#L28-29)
[warn]        +- default:ra-server-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.9.2: not found
```

What am I missing? Need to add another repository?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1.9.2 is only published for sbt 1, not for 0.13. Current sbt 1 version is 1.5.5.

Comment: Project uses sbt version 0.13.15. A quick test with sbt version 1.3.10 results in various build errors. So cannot easily upgrade sbt. Any way to use sbt-native-packager v1.9.2 with v0.13.15?

Comment: No. There is no way that could possibly work.

Comment: Okay. Project has now been updated to Play Framework 2.7 and SBT version 1.2.8. It will now build without error using *sbt-native-packager* plug-in version 1.9.2. But: Apparently some of the changes that are supposed to be in *sbt-native-packager* version 1.9.2 don't apply. Looks like it is still using an older version of sbt-native-packager even though version 1.9.2 is set explicitely in the `plugins.sbt` file. Any ideas?

Comment: Open a new question with details on how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Migrating to Play Framework 2.8 (sbt 1.3) has fixed it for me. For whatever reason, explicitely setting the "sbt-native-packager" plug-in to version v1.9.2 in my `plugins.sbt` file did **not** seem to have any effect with Play Framework 2.7 (also no error). Now, with Framework 2.8, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with a lot of effort I have now been able to migrate my project to Play Framework 2.8 and this seems to have fixed my problem! Under Framework version 2.6, it apparently was **not** possible to use sbt-native-packager 1.9.2 at all, because Framework version 2.6 uses an old version of SBT. And the newer version of sbt-native-packager is unavailable for that old SBT version, as it seems. Strangely enough, with Framework version 2.7, setting up sbt-native-packager 1.9.2 in my `plugins.sbt` file *did* work (there was **no** build error), but still the "old" version of sbt-native-packager was used! I have **no** idea why. It is fixed in Framework version 2.8, as far as I can tell.